# R- How to transform a date from an english format (Month-Day-Year) to another format?

Tags: r, datetime, anytime

I would like to transform `January 2, 2018 at 02:55PM` to datetime format .
I use the package anytime. I added a new format `addFormats("%B %d, %Y at %I:%M%p")` but it doesn't work.

`anytime(data$Date)` returns "2018-01-02 CET". I lose the hour..

Comment: Only questions in English here.

Comment: I made an attempt at translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume some format for creating the time string as follow `h <- "January 2, 2018 at 02:55PM"`

The key I found was a modification of the string, in removing "at " and "PM". I've done it in two step, but I guess someone could do this in just one step. I did not put format like you.

```
h <- "January 2, 2018 at 02:55PM"
h ; anytime(h)
#[1] "January 2, 2018 at 02:55PM"
#[1] "2018-01-02 CET"

h <- gsub("at ","", h,)
h ; anytime(h)
#[1] "January 2, 2018 02:55PM"
#[1] "2018-01-02 CET"

h <- gsub("PM","", h,)
h ; anytime(h)
#[1] "January 2, 2018 02:55"
#[1] "2018-01-02 02:55:00 CET"
```

Note that whitout seconds, it assume the hour with hour:minute:00.

## EDIT :

There is one regex to remove both patterns in one time

```
h <- "January 2, 2018 at 02:55PM"
h <- gsub("at |PM","",h)
anytime(h)
#[1] "2018-01-02 02:55:00 CET"
```